Radial (nonlinear) eigenfunctions of the $p$-Laplace operator
I am interested in solving
$- \Delta_p f + \lambda f |f|^{p - 2} = \delta_0$
in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for $1 < p < \infty$, where $\lambda > 0$ and we recall that $\Delta_p f := \nabla \cdot (|\nabla f|^{p - 2} \nabla f)$.
The case $p = 2$ is classical and may be solved by looking for radial solutions, which is equivalent to an ODE whose solution is classically known (see Screneed Poisson equation - Wikipedia). If we try to proceed as such for the present problem, we obtain the following ODE, which I do not know how to solve:
$$
- (p - 1) |f'(r)|^{p - 2} f''(r) - \frac{2}{r} |f'(r)|^{p - 2} f'(r) + \lambda f(r) |f(r)|^{p - 2} = 0.
$$
Any suggestion is appreciated.
